# Difference between FAR and FAR * used in winsock

Tags: c++, c, winapi, winsock

I would like to know the difference between `FAR` and `FAR *` used in
this function from *WinSock*.

```
int PASCAL FAR connect (SOCKET s, const struct sockaddr FAR * name, int len);
```

Comment: A far function is one outside of the current code segment.

Comment: The asterisk doesn't really belong to the `FAR` but to the type. So `name` is a pointer to a `struct sockaddr`. On an old 16-bit system the `FAR` would make it a 32-bit pointer to a `struct sockaddr`.

Answer (score 4):

You can safely ignore the `FAR` keywords as they are not used any more.

Long ago, in the times of Win16 there were 16 bit pointers (`NEAR`) and 32 bit pointers (`FAR`). Their handling was different and in some cases not simple. Bit since the beginning of the Win32 this difference has gone. Win64 is also not using the segmented memory model.

At the same time on the hardware level the segments are still present in the Intel architecture. But these details are completely hidden from the user mode programmers (and also from the kernel mode driver writers) by Windows.

You may still find these keywords in the header files because they do not harm anybody.

Answer (score 3):

In both cases they modify the size of pointers when this code is used in a segmented memory model. `const struct sockaddr FAR * name` says that name will be a 32-bit pointer. `int PASCAL FAR connect` says that any pointer to the connect function will be a 32-bit pointer. The alternative would be `NEAR` which would mean the pointers are 16-bit.

But no-one has used segmented memory models since Windows 3.1. They are so old I'm not even sure that I'm using the correct terminology. They are so old that I bet more than half of the regulars here will never have heard of them. So I think I can confidently say you can ignore any use of FAR, just pretend it doesn't exist.

Where did you see this?

Comment: I was reading Windows Sockets Version 1.1. Can you suggest me any latest Winsock book

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that book's about 20 years old. Seriously. Try Microsoft's official documentation instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740632(v=vs.85).aspx